# How to read in stream multiple .zip folder, unzip and write in stream each files contains by unzipp folder through Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, jupyter

I have archive with zip files that I would like to open 'through' Spark in streaming and write in streaming the unzip files in other directory that kip the name of the zip file(one by one).

```
    import zipfile
import io

def zip_extract(x):
    in_memory_data = io.BytesIO(x[1])
    file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")
    files = [i for i in file_obj.namelist()]
    return dict(zip(files, [file_obj.open(file).read() for file in files]))
```

Is there an easy way to read and write the above code in streaming ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Spark can't read archives out of the box.
A ZIP file is both archiving and compressing data. If you can, use a program like `gzip` to compress the data but keep each file separate, so don't archive multiple files into a single one.

If the archive is a given, and can't be changed. You can consider reading it with `sparkContext.binaryFiles`(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/index.html) This would allow you to have the zipped file in a byte array in spark, so you can write a mapper function which can unzip and return the content of the file. You can then flatten that result to get an RDD of the files' contents.

Comment: Thank you @Lior for your answer, do you have any example ? And I want ton know if we can make that in Python or we need use Scala ? Thank you.

Comment: Should be doable in Python, but I can't recommend Scala enough specifically when working with Spark. Unfortunately I don't have an example for it.

Comment: @MFatn , How did you approach to this finally?